# .htaccess virtual directory mapping and extracting variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to map requests as follows

```
    http://www.example.com/my_folder/XYZ/card.jpg
```

into

```
    http://www.example.com/script_folder/image.php?parameter=XYZ
```

my directory structure is as follows.

```
    .htaccess
    script_folder/
            - image.php
```

Please note that *my_folder* is a virtual folder which is non-existant. The folder doesn't have any .htaccess in any of it's parent directories. I'm using mod_rewrite.

so far I have managed to write this code in different ways but no luck

```
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RedirectMatch "^/my_folder/(.*)/card.jpg" "image.php?parameter=$1"
```

Please help me correct my htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing mod-alias with mod-rewrite. RedirectMatch is part of a diffrent module (mod alias).

Try this :

```
RedirectMatch ^/my_folder/(.+)/card.jpg$ /script_folder/image.php?perameter=$1
```

This will redirect **/my_folder/xyz/card.jpg** to **/script_folder/image.php?perameter=xyz** changing the address bar from typed url to a new url. If you want the browser to stay on the typed url, you can use the following mod rewrite based solution :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^my_folder/(.+)/card\.jpg$ /script_folder/image.php?perameter=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Suits my purpose but upon further checking I found that it allows urls like my_folder/ABC/DEF/card.jpg to be redirected too. Thank you so much sir

Comment: Change the pattern **(.+)** to **([^/]+)** to match the exact part of the uri.